# How to find the terms of Post-Newtonian approximation?

Tags: general-relativity, approximations, post-newtonian

I am studying the Damour paper on the Post-Minkowskian approximation to the 2 bodies problem in General Relativity ([paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1609.00354)) but can't really understand the explanation of the previous *state of the art*, namely the Post-Newtonian approximation: a way to "perturbe" the Newtonian flat space-time assuming small velocities.

I understand that, once is established that the two momentums $I_R$ and $I_\phi$ are the same in the *real* and *effective* scenario, one has to look for a map $f$ that connects the real and effective energies: $E^{eff}=f(E^{real})$ and this map will be expanded in a series of $\frac{1}{c^2}$. In the paper the $\alpha_i$ are the coefficients of this series. How does one calculate them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found another interesting [paper from 1998](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9811091) by Buonanno and Damour, and chapters 2, 3 and 4 cover the subject, so question solved.